# Adding conditional comment from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add a link element to an html conditional comment from the c# code-behind, but coming up completely blank.  Any elements within a conditional comment are, quite reasonably, not considered to "exist within the current context" by visual studio.

So, possibly, I can write the entire comment out from the code, but I can't seem to find any way to do that. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way: constructing an `HtmlString` and writing it to a `Literal`.

```
    var cc = new HtmlString("<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='ie_8_Styles.css' /><![endif]-->");
    lit_CustomIECSS.Text = cc.ToString();
```

Feels a little clunky, but it works. Very happy a accept a more stylish solution.